# How to get bitmap of a view?

Tags: android, bitmap, android-canvas, android-graphics, android-crop

Ok, so I'll try my best to explain my problem.
I have used this code to get a "screenshot" of my FrameLayout

```
/**
 * Function that takes a screenshot of the view passed and returns a bitmap for it.
 *
 * @param view {@link View}
 * @return screenshot of the view passed
 */
public Bitmap screenShot(View view) {
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(),
            view.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    view.draw(canvas);
    return bitmap;
}
```

Here is my FrameLayout

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame_layout_picture"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/photoImageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

    <com.my.android.util.DrawCustomView
        android:id="@+id/draw_custom_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</FrameLayout>
```

`DrawCustomView` is used to paint on `photoImageView`.

Now I also have different activity to crop image. So, I saved this bitmap (using `screenshot(view)`) in a file and send the file path to this crop activity. In my crop activity I am using https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper library's `CropImageView` to crop the image.
When I try to crop the painted photo sent to crop activity I get a weird crop, something like this :

The image doubles on cropping too much :
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4jK5QX65b0ZSHdMTWIzZXluZXc

Before zooming in :
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4jK5QX65b0ZeUk3NUlGUHRSQ0E

This is how a normal picture appears in crop activity :
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4jK5QX65b0ZNk9oSG1ZaGxYOVk

I also notice that the bounds for cropping are restricted to image size in the normal case but when edited using screenshot(), the bounds take the size of the screen.

I have tested my crop activity beforehand and it works fine for images sent from camera.
I also tried to send a picture that is not obtained using screenshot function, and it worked fine in crop activity.

I'll be happy to provide more info, any help is much appreciated... I am relatively new to android development :)

EDIT

This video might give more perspective to the problem
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4jK5QX65b0ZSUVFZDlQeTc4QnM

Answer (score 0):

You can try this method to capture a screenshot of your view.

```
 /**
  * this method capture the image from provided view and save it to application internal directory.
  *
  * @param view to capture image.
  * @return path of image saved in the phone.
  */
public static String captureScreenShotAndSave(Context mContext, View view) {
    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    String mPath = mContext.getApplicationContext().getExternalCacheDir() + "/" + "IMG_" + DateTimeUtils.getCurrentTimeStamp() + "_" + SHARE_IMAGE_NAME;

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(bitmap);
    view.draw(c);
    c.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, null);

    OutputStream fout = null;
    File imageFile = new File(mPath);
    try {
        fout = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);

        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, fout);//set image quality and formate as you required.
        fout.flush();
        fout.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return imageFile.getAbsolutePath();
}
```

You can call this method like `YourUtilsClass.captureScreenShotAndSave(mContext, mViewToCapture);`

Comment: Android studio can't resolve AppDelgate and DateTimeUtils.

Comment: Check my latest edit.

Comment: Unfortunately, same problem persists : drive.google.com/open?id=0B4jK5QX65b0ZSUVFZDlQeTc4QnM

Answer (score 0):

```
public static Bitmap shot(View view) {
    view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    Bitmap bitmap = view.getDrawingCache();
    view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
    return bitmap;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately didn't work, got this in crop activity https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4jK5QX65b0ZMlR1dk1zUXlvZ3c